# Display custom post type category taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type and a taxonomy which allows the user to select which category the post is in.

Here is my custom taxonomy:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_talcat_taxonomy', 0);
function create_Talcat_taxonomy()
{
    register_taxonomy ( 'Talcat', 'artist', array( 'hierarchical' =>
    true, 'label' => 'Categories', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true )
);
}
```

On my homepage I am querying the post_type=artist , which works fine and brings in my artist posts. However how can I print/display the name of the category that post belongs to and then link to that category page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are talking about terms, not categories. You can use [`wp_list_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) to retrieve and display the terms that a post belongs to.

Here is a working example from the codex. Remember the `$taxonomy` variable can be changed to `category` or any custom taxonomy

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'YOUR TAXONOMY NAME';

// get the term IDs assigned to post.
$post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
// separator between links
$separator = ', ';

if ( !empty( $post_terms ) && !is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {

   $term_ids = implode( ',' , $post_terms );
   $terms = wp_list_categories( 'title_li=&style=none&echo=0&taxonomy=' . $taxonomy . '&include=' . $term_ids );
   $terms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $terms ) ), $separator );

    // display post categories
 echo  $terms;
}
?>
```

Just a tip, don't use capital letters in your taxonomy name when registering it. It does lead to problems most of the time

Comment: This causes an error of syntax error, unexpected '>' on the line that says &post_terms.

Comment: Sorry, you are right about the syntax error. I posted that from my phone and for some reason it broke one of the single arrow. Corrected it

Answer (score 5):

I have managed to find a clean and simple way to achieve printing the taxonomy term assigned to the post with the following:

```
<?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'TAXONOMY NAME', ' ', ' / ' ); ?>
```

Using term retrieves the terms associated with the given object(s), in the supplied taxonomies.

[Here is a link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_terms) to the codex with examples and further detail.

Comment: I have to wait 2 days until I can accept it unfortunately.

Comment: No problem, don't forget to come back in two days. Unfortunately it is how the system works